# Currentsection list of theorems in scrartcl

Tags: koma-script, thmtools, etoc

Is there a handy way to include an `etoc`-like \localtableofcontents for theorems?

I have multiple environments defined with `thmtools` in a `scrartcl` document and would like to have a list of theorems of the current section at the beginning of each section. The question is similar to [Currentsection TOC in scrartcl?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361399/currentsection-toc-in-scrartcl) and [\tableofcontent[currentsection] in article or scrartcl?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371233/tableofcontentcurrentsection-in-article-or-scrartcl?noredirect=1#comment925247_371233) but for theorems. A call like `\locallistoftheorems` would be nice.

Update: The question is also somehow similar to [A list of theorems grouped into sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151157/a-list-of-theorems-grouped-into-sections) in the sense, that I could use that technique together with `etoc`s `\localtableofcontents` since my document has no subsections. But I would appreciate a less "hacky" approach which would be applicable in a broader field.

Comment: please add some code that we can start with else from scratch it is too much guess-work about what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `etoc`'s `\localtableofcontents` for that. See `24. Arbitrary “Lists Of...”,` in the [etoc manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc).